# Why is rz gate error not exactly zero in IBMQ washington device?

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience

I am looking at the calibration data for IBMQ's washington device (which is published daily) and am finding non-zero values for the field "rz_gate_error_value".

I used to think that RZ gates are implemented purely in software and have no errors (exactly zero error).

Please help me understand why is it not exactly zero.

Thanks!

Comment: The calibration data comes from the device, so it has errors and is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure but the IBMQ Washington device uses the RZ gate as a base gate like all other IBMQ devices. -Therefore I don't think the RZ gate is implemented purely in software.-

EDIT: As the comment of Egretta.Thula shows, the RZ Gate is implemented purely in software. The Answer to the other questions links to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.00858.pdf).
I was just briefly looking over the Conclusion where it mentions that the RZ gate is 'near-perfect'.

Comment: See the answer here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/29052/9474

Comment: It is near perfect, at least in the paper's setup, because an `rz` gate is applied always with an `rx` or `ry` gate. 

In the paper it is also mentioned that VZ-gates can correct unitary phase errors. How could they correct such errors if they are applied perfectly?

Answer (score 1):

How did you see the non-zero RZ gate error rates?

I retrieve the gate errors using this and the value is 0 for all 127 qubits.

```
# I am using a provider that has access to ibm_washington
ibm_washington = provider.get_backend('ibm_washington')
ibm_washington.properties().gate_property('rz')
```

Output

```
{(0,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (1,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (2,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (3,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (4,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (5,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (6,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (7,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (8,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (9,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (10,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (11,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (12,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (13,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (14,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (15,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (16,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (17,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (18,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (19,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (20,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (21,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (22,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (23,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (24,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (25,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (26,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (27,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (28,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (29,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (30,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (31,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (32,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (33,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (34,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (35,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (36,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (37,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (38,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (39,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (40,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (41,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (42,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (43,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (44,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (45,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (46,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (47,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (48,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (49,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (50,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (51,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (52,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (53,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (54,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (55,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (56,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (57,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (58,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (59,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (60,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (61,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (62,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (63,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (64,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (65,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (66,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (67,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (68,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (69,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (70,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (71,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (72,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (73,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (74,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (75,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (76,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (77,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (78,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (79,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (80,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (81,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (82,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (83,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (84,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (85,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (86,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (87,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (88,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (89,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (90,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (91,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (92,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (93,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (94,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (95,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (96,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (97,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (98,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (99,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (100,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (101,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (102,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (103,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (104,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (105,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (106,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (107,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (108,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (109,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (110,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (111,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (112,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (113,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (114,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (115,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (116,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (117,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (118,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (119,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (120,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (121,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (122,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (123,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (124,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (125,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))},
 (126,): {'gate_error': (0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
  'gate_length': (0.0,
   datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 13, 14, 42, tzinfo=tzlocal()))}}
```

```